# TTTAttributedLabel's attributedTruncationToken not working as expected

Tags: ios, iphone, uilabel, nsattributedstring, tttattributedlabel

In the label I'm using a attributed text which can contain urls, if the number of line exceed the limit, label should show 'continue reading' as attributedTruncationToken.

I'm observing two problems:
1)- Text just before 'continue reading' appeared as link and its clickable.
2)- If text which contains url in the last line, 'continue reading' gets event of url instead of custom scheme.

Video:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6gp0namrllplnrw/TTTAttributedLabel_Bug.mov?dl=0

Demo Code:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/72hz5q1j39umomh/Demo_Bug.zip?dl=0

[image]

Comment: did you solve the problem? I have the same problem